# Simple search and replace without regex

Tags: perl, bash, text

I've got a file with various wildcards in it that I want to be able to substitute from a (Bash) shell script. I've got the following which works great until one of the variables contains characters that are special to regexes:

```
VERSION="1.0"
perl -i -pe "s/VERSION/${VERSION}/g" txtfile.txt    # No problems here

APP_NAME="../../path/to/myapp"
perl -i -pe "s/APP_NAME/${APP_NAME}/g" txtfile.txt  # Error!
```

So instead I want something that just performs a literal text replacement rather than a regex. Are there any simple one-line invocations with Perl or another tool that will do this?

Comment: I think the answer is **"No, there is no string replace for literal strings in perl"**.  You have to use a regex and if you want the regex to be literal, you have to use `quotemeta` or `\Q \E` as described in [perldoc quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

Comment: For those arriving from search engine results looking for ways to avoid regular expressions (e.g., for performance reasons), [glenn jackman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970702/simple-search-and-replace-without-regex/7974404#7974404) and [Jess's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970702/simple-search-and-replace-without-regex/18794142#18794142) use *[substr()](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#substr-EXPR%2COFFSET%2CLENGTH%2CREPLACEMENT)* and *[index()](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#index-STR%2CSUBSTR%2CPOSITION)* to achieve that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the following:

```
perl -i -pe "s|APP_NAME|\\Q${APP_NAME}|g" txtfile.txt
```

Since a vertical bar is not a legal character as part of a path, you are good to go.

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick!  I was forgetting that the regexp in itself wasn't the problem, rather the whole substitution command, so changing the delimiter worked.

Comment: On Unix, `|` is a valid path character. In fact, all characters other than `NUL` (`\0`) are valid (if uncommon) in filenames on Unix. Which is why you should simply use the built-in quotation mechanism, as Borodin suggests below.

Comment: @the_mandrill: Functionality is a poor measure of the *best solution*.

Comment: Use `str =~ s/\Q$replace_this\E/$with_this/;` in case of variables

Answer (score 20):

The 'proper' way to do this is to escape the contents of the shell variables so that they aren't seen as special regex characters. You can do this in Perl with \Q, as in

```
s/APP_NAME/\Q${APP_NAME}/g
```

but when called from a shell script the backslash must be doubled to avoid it being lost, like so

```
perl -i -pe "s/APP_NAME/\\Q${APP_NAME}/g" txtfile.txt
```

But I suggest that it would be far easier to write the entire script in Perl

Comment: Taking a cruise through some of your regex answers—nice to soak up another person's regex style. :)

Comment: With `APP_NAME="../../path/to/myapp"` (from the question), this command fails, due to the `/` in the variable, which terminates the replacement part of the regex. Is there a general-purpose approach?

Comment: @TomFenech: Six years on I'm not so sure of myself! The problem is that, in a Perl one-liner using bash, there are two levels of escaping going on. First, bash will process the string `perl -i -pe "s/APP_NAME/${APP_NAME}/g" txtfile.txt` and apply any interpolations of its own, and then perl will process the result and do the same thing in its turn. I'm nowhere near a PC for now, but I think this should be fixed.

Comment: This even worked when I needed to parameterize a string that included the middle delimiting `/` ( `s/.../.../g`. I did something like `perl -i -p0e 's/blah\Q${variable}/s'` (notice, that's missing the dividing `/`, but that was in my variable I passed from a file with `while`).

Answer (score 9):

I don't particularly like this answer because there should be a better way to do a literal replace in Perl.  `\Q` is cryptic. Using `quotemeta` adds extra lines of code.

But...  You can use `substr` to replace a portion of a string.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $name = "Jess.*";
my $sentence = "Hi, my name is Jess.*, dude.\n";
my $new_name = "Prince//";
my $name_idx = index $sentence, $name;
if ($name_idx >= 0) {
    substr($sentence, $name_idx, length($name), $new_name);
}
print $sentence;
```

#### Output:

```
Hi, my name is Prince//, dude.
```

Comment: Your post is so heavily underrated. Thank you sir from saving me from those regexes! Sometimes, you just need something else than a regex to replace stuff (eg. when replacing regexes in a string).

Comment: @user1834095: *"`\Q` is cryptic. Using `quotemeta` adds extra lines of code"*. But neither are a problem as long as the program is written well. Regular expressions are a natural extension of the file globs that bash provides, which are equally cryptic but are just part of life. I agree that `substr` as an *lvalue* is a useful idiom, but `index` has had its day, especially now that we have `@-` and `@+`. All of this is vastly improved in Perl 6!

Comment: I've had another reason to end up here, but found that  finding lines to skip using `index()` is significantly faster then doing regular expression match for fixed string, even when caching regex with `/o` or `qr///`. (some 25% speedup in my use case in perl 5.36.0).

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to use a regular expression for this (using *[substr()](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#substr-EXPR%2COFFSET%2CLENGTH%2CREPLACEMENT)*, *[index()](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#index-STR%2CSUBSTR%2CPOSITION)*, and *[length()](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#length-EXPR)*):

```
perl -pe '
  foreach $var ("VERSION", "APP_NAME") {
    while (($i = index($_, $var)) != -1) {
      substr($_, $i, length($var)) = $ENV{$var};
    }
  }
'
```

Make sure you `export` your variables.

Comment: Ok but, I'm really wondering if a for + while + substr + length is really better than a simple substitution from a performance point of view...

Comment: That's the kind of question that's answered with benchmarking. Try it, time it, and see.

Comment: No need to test something for which I already know the answer ;) For sure, your solution is not better than a simple substitution, at least with Perl ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
 perl -i -pe "\$r = qq/\Q${APP_NAME}\E/; s/APP_NAME/\$r/go"
```

Rationale: *[Escape sequences](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Escape-sequences)*

> ```
> \Q          quote (disable) pattern metacharacters until \E
> \E          end either case modification or quoted section, think vi
> ```

The `qq/abc/` syntax is used instead of `"abc"` to [double-quote](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#qq/STRING/) the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex but escape any special characters.

Something like this may work.

```
APP_NAME="../../path/to/myapp"
APP_NAME=`echo "$APP_NAME" | sed -e '{s:/:\/:}'`
perl -i -pe "s/APP_NAME/${APP_NAME}/g" txtfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a working solution, partly based on bits and pieces from other peoples' answers:

```
app_name='../../path/to/myapp'
perl -pe "\$r = q/${app_name//\//\\/}/; s/APP_NAME/\$r/g" <<<'APP_NAME'
```

This creates a Perl variable, `$r`, from the result of the shell parameter expansion:

```
${app_name//\//\\/}

${            # Open parameter expansion
app_name      # Variable name
//            # Start global substitution
\/            # Match / (backslash-escaped to avoid being interpreted as delimiter)
/             # Delimiter
\\/           # Replace with \/ (literal backslash needs to be escaped)
}             # Close parameter expansion
```

All that work is needed to prevent forward slashes inside the variable from being treated as Perl syntax, which would otherwise close the `q//` quotes around the string.

In the replacement part, use the variable `$r` (the `$` is escaped, to prevent it from being treated as a shell variable within double quotes).

Testing it out:

```
$ app_name='../../path/to/myapp'
$ perl -pe "\$r = q/${app_name//\//\\/}/; s/APP_NAME/\$r/g" <<<'APP_NAME'
../../path/to/myapp
```