# Use ~ in Perl search and replace

Tags: perl, replace

I want to replace a placeholder in all files under a directory with a string that is generated from user input. This input can contain `/ : . ~`

I chose Perl for this task.

```
perl -p -i -e "s/__MY_PLACEHOLDER__/$user_input/g" `find my_dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0`
```

Now, `~` is a reserved character in Perl. How can I escape `~` in `$user_input`? `\~` does not work.

Comment: I was going to propose [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7970702/176646) as a duplicate, but I just don't like the accepted answer. You've actually combined two common (but good!) questions: 1) how can I pass a shell variable to Perl? and 2) how can I escape special characters in a regex? I can't find a suitable question that addresses both of those at once, so maybe this can become a new canonical question.

Comment: You should always wrap Perl one-liners in single quotes on \*nix. It's just too easy to accidentally interpolate a shell variable by accident, or trigger a history command (e.g. `perl -e"s!foo!bar!"` errors out with `"bash: !foo!bar!": event not found` in bash). You should either use Perl's `%ENV` hash or pass the bash variables as arguments to the Perl script. There are several nice posts about this, I'll try to find them for you.

Comment: I would hasten to point out that your `perl` will not do what you expect it to do when the `find` locates files that contain spaces.

Comment: @DravSloan That is true. I am getting by that with a naming convention for my directories --which works for my special use case. But in the interest of leaving a reusable solution for others, the accepted solution must work for files that have spaces in their names too.

Comment: why not `find my_dir -type f -exec perl -i -pe 'commands' {} +` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, `~` isn't special in double-quote string literals such as the replacement expression of `s///`. A few others are special, however. Of the four characters you listed, `/` is special when `/` is used as the delimiter as is the case here.

---

Don't try to generate Perl code from the shell! Use one of the following:

```
export $user_input
perl -i -pe's/__MY_PLACEHOLDER__/$ENV{user_input}/g'
```

or

```
USER_INPUT=$user_input perl -i -pe's/__MY_PLACEHOLDER__/$ENV{USER_INPUT}/g'
```

or

```
perl -i -pe'
   BEGIN { $user_input = shift }
   s/__MY_PLACEHOLDER__/$user_input/g
' "$user_input"
```

---

By the way, you really missed the point of `xargs`!

```
perl ... `find my_dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0`
```

is no different than

```
perl ... `find my_dir -type f`
```

What you wanted is

```
find my_dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 perl ...
```

This will pass the file names to `perl` unmangled. It will even call `perl` more than once with different batches of arguments if necessary to avoid hitting command line length limits.